# Use Ui-Router's ui-sref Just to Set Query Params

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have the following link.

```
<a ui-sref="...">Clicking this adds ?test=true to the query params.</a>
```

Is there a way to use the ui-sref attribute to just change query params without reloading the page or directing to another function?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to do it by passing the arguments with the state.

try:-

```
<a ui-sref="yourStateName({test:true})">Clicking this adds ?test=true to the query params.</a>
```

**[Usage:](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)**

> ui-sref='stateName' - Navigate to state, no params. 'stateName' can be any valid absolute or relative state, following the same syntax rules as $state.go()
>
> ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})' - Navigate to state, with params.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat you need to specify it in your route as well. i.e example:-    `url: "/route1?test",` How does your route look like? Hover over route1 in this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/peERl4?p=preview, you will see test=true query string parameter

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat Yeah i assumed you already have them in your route... If you have multiple query params set that up in your route ex:- `url: "/route1?test1&test"` and pass them in the respective key.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent it from reloading the page?

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat did you try turning off [reloadOnSearch](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/125) option?

Answer (score 11):

Just define the names of query params in the state url

```
$stateProvider.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts?test&answer',
    views: {
      content: {
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts/index',
        controller: 'PostsController'
      },
      navbar: {
        templateUrl: 'templates/partials/navbar'
      }
    }
  })
```

And use like this

```
<a ui-sref="posts({test: true, answer: false})">Next Page</a>
```

I am using ui-router version `0.2.15`

Answer (score 10):

In combination with PSL's answer, to prevent refreshing when setting up the state, just use the property `reloadOnSearch: false`.

```
.state('myState', {
      url: '/myState?test',
      reloadOnSearch : false,
      ...
    })
```

As long as your queries then take place within this same state.