# Use angular ui route to pass query parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular ui route and I'm trying to pass query parameters but it doesn't work. I have followed the official wiki.

In the view I have the following code very simple

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <a ng-href="#/foo/bar?param={{make}}"><li>{{make}}</li></a>
</div>
```

and this is the config

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        templateUrl: '/partials/foo.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      })
      .state('foo.bar', {
        url: '/bar?param',
        templateUrl: 'partials/foo.bar.html',
        controller: 'SecondaryController'
      });
  }
```

but when I click on the link in the view the url I get it is what I get but the route doesn't receive the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ui-sref` directive to generate `href` link

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <a ui-sref="foo.bar({param: make})"><li>{{make}}</li></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Already done that as suggested to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569346/use-ui-routers-ui-sref-just-to-set-query-params

Comment: Unfortunately the make contains some spaces and I got errors

Comment: @Mazzy what do you mean by `make` contains some space?

Comment: make could be for example `The Facebook'. As you might see there are space

Comment: @Mazzy you should look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639852/how-can-i-pass-data-with-urls-to-ui-sref where I solved the problem what you are getting

Comment: @Mazzy I know..I'm asking that to downvoter..someone is downvoting my answers randomly..I don't know who is he :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74967/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-mazzy).

Comment: the make variable need to be escaped inside param?

Comment: yes..you should add the code which I suggested in answer

Comment: then should be {param: {{make}}} or {param: make}?

Comment: and the url in the route config which should be `foo?param`

Comment: @Mazzy go through this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1119#issuecomment-64696060

Comment: now the make is an id and it doesn't have spaces but still doesn't work

Comment: I have accepted because you answer is right. Now I have another issue. The url in the browser has query param attached to it but the controller is not called correctly